# spring cloud feign invoke a method for upload file throws exception param is not present

Tags: spring, cloud, feign

feignclient:

```
@FeignClient(value = "code-analysis")
public interface ICodeAnalysisService{
    @PostMapping({"/cache"})
    ResultVO<String> postResultCache(@RequestParam(value = "file",required = false) MultipartFile var1, @Valid @RequestPart("codeConfiguration") CodeConfigurationVO var2);
}
```

invoke client:

```
codeAnalysisService.postResultCache(file,codeConfig)
```

exception is codeConfiguration is not present

Comment: Hello! Could you please post a stack-trace?

Answer (score 0):

final solution is:
modify the api to:

```
ResultVO<String> postResultCacheInner(@RequestPart(value = "file",required = false) MultipartFile file,@RequestParam("codeConfiguration") String codeConfiguration);
```

invoke client:

```
codeAnalysisService.postResultCache(file,codeConfig);
```

and codeConfig is String type,at last deserialize the codeConfig.